# "to help other people to choose" vs. "to help other people choose" - is the former correct?

Tags: vocabulary

I have some doubts about verb patterns. I know "to help other people choose" is correct. What about "to help other people *to* choose"?

It's usually easy for me to ascertain the correct use of some verb patterns when talking, but I struggle to understand the rules.

Comment: _Help_ takes an [infinitive complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf), and in the [B configuration](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) (as here), the complementizer _to_ is optional. So they're both right, and there's no difference except an extra unstressed syllable.

Comment: If you're a native speaker, you should trust your grammatical judgement (provided you didn't learn it in school).

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable options.

To my nonnative ear, "to help someone do" sounds more typical of AE than BE.