# "Assist someone do" vs. "assist someone to do (or "in/with" doing)"

Tags: grammar, idioms, word-usage, malapropisms

I just recently came across "assist someone do" searching Google for examples to my previous question, and would like to check with you whether it is an acceptable option to "assist someone to do (or "in/with" doing)", or a snapshot of language in transition -- analogous with "help someone do" -- that I caught here.

Please consider the following examples for this:

> NAFDAC is to assist you do your business right.[source](http://businessdayonline.com/2013/03/nafdac-assures-small-business-operators-on-prompt-product-registration/)
>
> Our company will assist you do your assignments...[source](http://bestcustomessaywriting.com/oxford-writing-style.html)
>
> (Go down to bottom of page and look up "Transtec Inc., 
>   Robert Rasmussen PE") We are a specialty engineering company with award-winning expertise in pavements and pavement materials. We can assist you do your job better.[source](http://www.topengineeringcompanies.com/in/austin-tx)

Comment: Normally _assist_ takes an infinitive **with** _to_ in the B configuration; omitting it is not correct. This may be an analogy with _help_, which does allow optional _to_-deletion in the B configuration. This came up in [a recent question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/155413/15299).

Comment: It's common for advertising slogans to be a bit ungrammatical, as these examples are. It makes them more memorable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct form, as you point out, is 'to assist someone to do (or "in/with" doing)"'.

Quote 1 is from an ESL source, and could be interpreted as 'here to insist you do' or 'here to help you [to] do'.

Quote 2 is ungrammatical. It should be 'assist you in/with doing'.

I couldn't locate quote 3, but comment is as per quote 2.

(Amended and updated based on comment below)